# Django: mostrar todas las variables en un template

Tags: python, django

tengo la siguiente función que devuelve un JSON:

```
class HotelService(models.Model):
    def get_avail_and_rates(self, rq):
        cabeceras = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'action': 'getavailandrates',
            'format': 'json',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
        }
        url = 'http://connectivity.dingus-services.com/services/v4/hotelservice.ashx'
        response = requests.post(url, data=rq, headers=cabeceras)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            results = response.json()
        else:
            results = "Error"
        return results
```

En views.py llamo a la función pasándole los parámetros y se paso el resultado a un template

```
hs = HotelService()
hotels_list = hs.get_avail_and_rates(rq)
template = loader.get_template('prueba.html')
return render(request, 'prueba.html', hotels_list)
```

A la hora de pintarlo en prueba.html hago lo siguiente:

```
{% for result in hotels_list %}
    <p>{{ result }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Esto no de vuelve nada. Lo he intendado de muchas formas pero no consigo mostrar los datos. ¿Cómo lo mostraríais vosotro? Y otra pregunta: ¿Hay alguna forma de ver lo que devuelve una función antes de mostrarla en un template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me contesto a mi mismo:
Para ver todo lo que se le pasa a un template se puede utilizar en la plantilla `{% debug %}`

Esto solo funciona si en settings.py está `DEBUG = True`

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar errores usa el siguiente script para asignar el valor a DEBUG:
settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
import sys
RUNNING_DEVSERVER = (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'runserver')
if RUNNING_DEVSERVER == True:
    DEBUG = True
```